# How can I change the innerHTML of div with a variable, inside the scope function in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

I have 2 HTML pages. In my index.html page you can see products information that comes from JSON file. I need to have detail of product in detail.html page when people click on particular product. Alert can show the details but unfortunately the innerHTML of my `<p>` does not change, please guide me.

```
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppController">
<div id="serachWrapper">
  <h1 id="headerTopic">Our Products</h1>
  <input id="searchInput" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search products" ng-model="searchquery"/>
  <table id="searchTable">
    <thead id="tbHead">
      <tr class="tbRow">
        <th class="tbTopics">ID</th>
        <th class="tbTopics">Name</th>
        <th class="tbTopics">Color</th>
        <th class="tbTopics">Type</th>
        <th class="tbTopics">Capacity</th>
        <th class="tbTopics">Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbBody">
      <tr class="tbRow" ng-repeat="x in myData | filter:searchquery ">
        <td class="tbcontents" ><a href="detail.html" ng-click="go(x)">{{x.id}}</a></td>
        <td class="tbcontents"><a href="detail.html" ng-click="go(x)">{{x.name}}</a></td>
        <td class="tbcontents"><a href="detail.html" ng-click="go(x)">{{x.color}}</a></td>
        <td class="tbcontents"><a href="detail.html" ng-click="go(x)">{{x.type}}</a></td>
        <td class="tbcontents"><a href="detail.html" ng-click="go(x)">{{x.capacity}}</a></td>
        <td class="tbcontents"><a href="detail.html" ng-click="go(x)">{{x.price}}</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And this is my Angular js code:

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
  app.controller('AppController', AppController);

  function AppController($scope , $http) {
   $http.get("products.json").success(function(myData){
       $scope.myData = myData;

       $scope.go = function(item){
           var detail = item.detail;
           var productDetail = angular.element(document.getElementById('product-detail')).html();
           productDetail = detail;
           alert(detail)
           };
     });
  }
```

Comment: in my detail.html page I just have a <p> tag.                                                                                                     <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppController">
     <p id="product-detail">We should see here the details</p>
  </div>

Answer (score 0):

You can keep both codes in the page and to solve this with an *ng-if* directive

[Angular ng-if directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

```
<body ng-app="ngAnimate">
  <label>Click me: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-init="checked=true" /></label><br/>
Show when checked:
  <span ng-if="checked" class="animate-if">
   This is removed when the checkbox is unchecked.
  </span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is your $scope.go function defined inside the http.get request?

Try:

```
function AppController($scope , $http) {

    $http.get("products.json").success(function(myData){
       $scope.myData = myData;
     });

    $scope.go = function(item) {
        var detail = item.detail;
        var productDetail = angular.element(document.getElementById('product-detail')).html();
        productDetail = detail;
        alert(detail)
     };
}
```

Comment: I moved $scope.go function outside the http.get but the problem still exist.